# Magento version upgrade permission issue

Tags: magento-1.9, php, upgrade, permissions

I am trying to update magento version from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.2.1 (latest version). However my website have some soft links. For example my website domain is pointing to /var/www/html/ folder. Inside this I have created some softlinks to other folders which are created under /var/www/magento/ folder.

When I am trying to update magento version from admin section magento connect manager, it is giving me permission error and conflicts with cummunity package installer.

Is it possible that mangento version can update with these softlinks using magento connect. Please help.

Comment: Updating Magento via Magento connect is not recommended, especially in your case where your installation has been customised. Upgrade manually via the command line where you have full control over the file copy/replace process.

Answer (score 1):

**If this is the entire question:**
*Is it possible that mangento version can update with these softlinks using magento connect. Please help.*

**The answer is:**
It is not possible for Magento Connect to update your Symlinks

You should use SSH to update Magento in your "Linked folders"